# Sync parse getInBackground() with another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, parse-platform

In android, we can sync two threads with tools like pipes, handlers, shared memory ... I would like to do this with a "parse thread". The idea is that we have two threads, main thread and the thread created by getInBackground() like a simple query:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // object will be your game score
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

I do not want to show a white screen forcing to the user wait. I would like to show a cached listView of the last results (main thread), while the device is downloading the data (Parse thread). When the device would have downloaded all the information, the listView must be updated with the new data. 
I do not know If I have explained myself propertly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

in the [doInBackGround()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) method do your download
and in [onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) method do the ListView update